# How do i Find all registers of one only column in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

How do i Find all registers of one only column in sails

my model is:

**models/Blog.js**

```
module.exports = {
    schema: true,
    attributes: {
        title:'string',
        content:{
            type:'string',
            required: true
        }
    }
};
```

my controller:
**controllers/BlogController.js**

```
module.exports = {

    index: function (req, res) {

        Blog.find()
        .exec(function (err, content) {
          if (err) {
            res.send(400);
          } else {
            res.view({OnlyContent:content}); // Only view all Content ?
          }
        });

    },
_config: {}
};
```

Comment: There's no "select" feature in Waterline (the Sails ORM) currently, if that's what you're asking.  But with a little research you can find many inventive ways using Javascript to pull one field out of an array of objects.  Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only send the data of *content* to your client, you need to loop through the returned array of *blogs* and filter out the *content*.

```
index: function (req, res) {

    Blog.find().exec(function (err, allBlogs) {
        if (err) { 
            res.send(400);
        } else {
            var allContent = [];
            allBlogs.forEach(function (blog) {
                allContent.push(blog.content);
            })

            res.view({
                OnlyContent: allContent
            });
        }
    });
}
```